# Micro timestamp and/or random string to file name

Tags: php, file-upload

So part of my upload file is setting the name of the file but I am struggling to get it to append a time stamp onto the file name or set a random string or both?

Here is where it is setting the file name and type:

```
        if (
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], "../uploads/{$_FILES['upload']['name']}")){
            print_r($_FILES);
            echo '<p><em>the file has been uploaded</em></p>';
        } // END OF MOVE.... IF.
```

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can name your files as you want/need, there is no convention.

Comment: I want to ensure no two files are the same file name? Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the timestamp is a good idea. Just do:

```
$date = new DateTime();
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], 
        "../uploads/" . $date->getTimestamp() . "_{$_FILES['upload']['name']}")){
     print_r($_FILES);
     echo '<p><em>the file has been uploaded</em></p>';
}
```

Note that I have added an underscore `_` after the timestamp so that it becomes easier for you to remove the timestamp if you need to get the initial filename again:

```
substr($filename, strpos($filename, '_'), strlen($filename));
```

Comment: Hey thanks - is there a way to add the timestamp at the start so before the name?

Comment: That seems to pump out the file like this: me 2.jpg_1433094706

Comment: Ah sorry I didnt see the second part! Fandabidoso! Amazing it works :)

Comment: Oh that's true, let's put the timestamp at the beginning of the filename then